# Problems converting Visual Studio 2005 solution to VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005

Convertion fails with the error messages for the projects like the following:

```
VCConvertEngine.dll encountered an error. 
VCConvertEngine could not convert attribute ConfigurationType = 4 under Configuration Debug|Win32. 
VCConvertEngine could not convert attribute CharacterSet = 1 under Configuration Debug|Win32. 
The expression "[System.IO.Path]::Combine(D:\Work\iVisit2010\branches\echo\src\common\, "D:\Work\iVisit2010\branches\echo\src\\bins\Win32\Debug"\common.lib)" cannot be evaluated. Illegal characters in path. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 
Project upgrade failed.
```

Could anyone help, please? (The solution contains many projects.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion : use VC2008 Express to convert first, and after using VC2008 project convert to VC2010.

Comment: Well, that helped a bit. 2005 -> 2008 successful, 2008 -> 2010 failed but there's just one error for every project: 

`Unable to read the project file "common.vcxproj". C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(36,5): The expression "[System.IO.Path]::Combine(D:\Work\iVisit2010\branches\echo\src\common\, "D:\Work\iVisit2010\branches\echo\src\\bins\Win32\Debug"\common.lib)" cannot be evaluated. Illegal characters in path. 
Project upgrade failed.`

Something with paths?